# Fuse for reverse lights

Tags: troubleshooting

Please I have no working reverse lights on my 2003 Subaru Outback and don’t know where to find the fuse for it. The globes are fine found those. I know the fuse box is under the hood but I don’t know what fuses to take outhelp needed please. Don’t be very technical as I’m not

Comment: There should be two fuse boxes, one inside in the passenger compartment and one under hood. More than likely the fuse is in the passenger compartment. If you look at the panel which covers the fuses, there should be a map to the fuses (both under hood and passenger compartment fuse boxes).

Comment: While there is usually a legend in the fuse panel lid, a more detailed version is usually in the owner's handbook, and, this may help as some fuses supply more than one item in many cases.

Comment: http://www.subaruoutback.org/forums/80-electrical-electronics/45495-no-reverse-lights-inhibitor-switch-good-fuse-good-bulbs-good-2.html#/topics/45495?page=2

Comment: There should be a fuse panel behind the coin tray, fuse 18 is for reverse lights.

Answer (score 2):

According to http://www.autogenius.info/subaru-outback-2003-fuse-box-diagram-2/ there should be a fuse box **behind your coin tray**.

The diagram and fuses may vary depending on your engine.
However, on **both** of those engine models, the backup should be on **#18*.**
* Please check the legacy on your fuse box to confirm, and don't assume I know what I'm talking about.

Here's a **step by step tutorial** right here on how to **locate** the fusebox and **change** the fuses right here: https://www.carcarekiosk.com/video/2001_Subaru_Outback_Limited_2.5L_4_Cyl._Wagon/fuse_interior/replace

On both models, according to the link above, it's supposed to be a **15A fuse** that should look like this: [image]

**2.5L**
[image]

---

**3.0L Model**
[image]